# Resolving IDbSet<T> from AutoFac

Tags: entity-framework, autofac

I would like to implement generic repository pattern with `IDbSet<>` interface of Entity Framework.

When i ask `IDbSet<T>` from Autofac, It should resolve `IDbContext` then call its `Set<T>` method to return the concrete type of `IDbSet<T>`

As an example, it should be doing something like this:

```
builder.Register<IDbSet<T>>(context => context.Resolve<IDbContext>().Set<T>());
```

How can i achive this with Autofac?

Comment: I really like this pattern its a nice way of leveraging UoW in EF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7997162/872395

that the only solution is to create a custom `IRegistrationSource` where you create the  closed registrations:

```
public class DbSetRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    public bool IsAdapterForIndividualComponents
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(
        Service service,
        Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        var swt = service as IServiceWithType;
        if (swt == null || !swt.ServiceType.IsGenericType)
            yield break;

        var def = swt.ServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        if (def != typeof(IDbSet<>))
            yield break;

        // if you have one `IDBContext` registeration you don't need the
        // foreach over the registrationAccessor(dbContextServices)

        yield return RegistrationBuilder.ForDelegate((c, p) =>
        {
            var dBContext = c.Resolve<IDBContext>();
            var m = dBContext.GetType().GetMethod("Set", new Type[] {});
            var method = 
                m.MakeGenericMethod(swt.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments());
            return method.Invoke(dBContext, null);
        })
                .As(service)
                .CreateRegistration();
    }
}
```

The usage is very simple:

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
containerBuilder.RegisterSource(new DbSetRegistrationSource());
containerBuilder.RegisterType<DbContext>().As<IDBContext>();
var container = containerBuilder.Build();
```

Comment: Thank you, apparently IRegistrationSource is God mode cheating for Autofac